# jquery using waypoint get id of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

i'am using jquery waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#docs) to check if an element is the view of the browser, here the html:

```
<div class="container" id="container_1">1. Container</div>
<div class="container" id="container_2">2. Container</div>
<div class="container" id="container_3">3. Container</div>
<div class="container" id="container_4">4. Container</div>
```

here the js

```
$('#container_1').waypoint(function() {
     console.log("container 1 is visible");
});
```

this works fine!

But is it possible to find out the current id of the element which is in view and the waypoint get fired? something like this:

```
$('.container').waypoint(function() {
         console.log("id of element: " + $(this).attr('id');
    });
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis: `)` at the end of console.log otherwise it would work.

```
$('.container').waypoint(function() {
         console.log("id of element: " + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

If you are confusing, you can use like this too:

```
$('.container').waypoint(function() {
    var $this = $('.container');         
    console.log("id of element: " + $this.attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

In waypoints.js I've found that `this` refers to a waypoints internal object. If you console.log it though, you easily find how to select that element with jquery.

```
handler: function (direction){
    var DOMElement = $(this.element);
    console.log($(this.element).attr('data-id');
}
```

Also... [element attribute ID return undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816909/element-attribute-id-return-undefined/35137055#35137055)