# Getting an #id from jQuery's this

Tags: jquery, this

How do I get the ID associated with the *this* keyword? I've tried several things from SO pages but here is where I've decided to open the question:

```
$('.anySelector').waypoint(function() {
    console.log(this); // entire selector's content
    var thisContent = this;
    console.log($(thisContent).attr('id')); // undefined
});
```

Comment: `console.log(jQuery(this).attr('id'))` is enough

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery using waypoint get id of element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232457/jquery-using-waypoint-get-id-of-element)

Comment: This has nothing to do with waypoints. Its a jQuery question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `this` really is a [DOM Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) (which is very probable using jQuery) it is as simple as just accessing the `id` property of the element.

```
jQuery( '.anySelector' ).waypoint( function() {
    console.log( this.id );
} );
```

If you really need to go the jQuery way (i.e. using the `attr` method) you must turn `this` into a jQuery object first:

```
jQuery( '.anySelector' ).waypoint( function() {
    console.log( jQuery( this ).attr( 'id' ) );
} );
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's happening in your case without a test example (e.g. a jsfiddle)… I could guess that the current element does not have an ID attribute. Anyway the following is true: `this.id === jQuery( this ).attr( 'id' )`. The difference is the unnecessary method call overhead when using jQuery…