# element attribute ID return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I tried to work with `waypoints.js` and make menu element active, when user scroll to it. As I can see, waypoints works well, but I can't get current section `id`... Console always said `undefined`.

So, what I'm doing wrong?

My script is:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var sections = jQuery('section');
    var navigation_links = jQuery('nav a');

    sections.waypoint({
    handler: function(direction) {
        var active_section;
        active_section = jQuery(this);
        if (direction === "up") active_section = active_section.prev();
        var active_link = jQuery('nav a[href="#' + active_section.attr("id") + '"]');
        navigation_links.parent().removeClass("active");
        active_link.parent().addClass("active");
        active_section.addClass("active-section");
        console.log(active_section.attr("id"))
    },
    offset: '35%'
    });
});
```

My HTML `nav` is:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#spec">What we do</a></li>
    <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tools">Tools</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contacts">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

My HTML `section` is:

```
<section id="home">
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>...</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Im thinking your problem might be with this line ` if (direction === "up") active_section = active_section.prev();` This will change the elements and perhaps the previous element doesnt have an id

Comment: ↑↑↑ ya check what is `active_section` just before getting its ID. Is it expected element?

Comment: @A. Wolff `active_section` show item correctly... But if I try to get its attribute ID, it show me `undefined`.

@AmmarCSE I tried to remove that completely, but had same issue...:/

Comment: @s.spirit provide sample replicating your issue e.g a jsFiddle

Comment: as i can test it, it works as expected, returns `undefined` only if `home` is active section, and then previous element isn't a section  http://jsfiddle.net/voew4bjk/

Comment: You're using version 3.x of Waypoints? If you are, `jQuery(this)` isn't going to work because `this` isn't the element, it's a Waypoint instance. If you're using 3.x you should use `jQuery(this.element)`.

Answer (score 3):

In waypoints.js I've found that `this` refers to a waypoints internal object. If you console.log it though, you easily find how to select that element with jquery.

```
handler: function (direction){
    var DOMElement = $(this.element);
    console.log($(this.element).attr('data-id');
}
```

Comment: Good observation!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by **@AmmarCSE** the problem is indeed with `if (direction === "up") active_section = active_section.prev();`. Basically if the previous element does not have an `id` then `undefined` will be printed in the console. A way to avoid this is to check that the previous element has an `id` (check and make sure it's not `undefined`), an only then set `active_section` like so:

```
var prev_section_id = active_section.prev().attr("id");
if (direction === "up" && typeof prev_section_id != 'undefined') 
    active_section = active_section.prev();
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mzghj4kf/)

Comment: I don't know, whats happen, but still get `undefined`. Even remove `if (direction === "up") active_section = active_section.prev();` or try your example...:/

Comment: @s.spirit, see the fiddle. He put a check to see if the previous element has an id or not. In the fiddle, it is working

Comment: @s.spirit That's odd, the example I gave has the same code you gave in your example. with `if (direction === "up...` and the `home2` removed `home` should be printing in the console. When I had the same code as you I got `undefined` and `home`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, only this will not return the id

```
$('.section').waypoint(function(){alert('this.element.id');});
```